# Hide Emacs initial buffer list when opening 3+ files

Tags: emacs

When I open 3 or more files at once with Emacs, e.g.

```
emacs file-1.txt file-2.txt file-3.txt ...
```

then the initial Emacs view is two panes, one for one of the files, and the other for the buffer list. Is there a way to change this behavior? I'd like to just show a single pane displaying one of the files. (If there's a way to show just the buffer list, that might be nice too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `(setq inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)` will skip showing the buffer list.

If you mostly care about avoiding window splits, you can add the following to your ~/.emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'delete-other-windows)
```

Comment: That gets me half-way there, but Emacs still splits into two panes, which is actually the annoying part. Didn't see any other obvious `inhibit-startup-*` variables, suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any obvious way to prevent the splits, but see my updated answer for a way to undo the splits.